# Tool, menu strip - how do I change their locations in c# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I noticed that tool and menu strips are very restrictive.

Is there any way to change the location of a toolstrip or menustrip? I want to have a drop down menu in a custom location on my winforms application (I'm using c#).

If not, is there any other dropdown menu type component I can try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that.

- Drag and drop MenuStrip
- Select it and Goto->Properties
- Set Dock-> None
- Then move anywhere as you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a [`ToolStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at any location if you set the [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `DockStyle.None`.

Alternatively, you can use a [`ContextMenuStrip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and show it manually with one of the [`ContextMenuStrip.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.Show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.