# Change menu strip color .NET FRAMEWORK C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menustrip

I'm working with .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8 with `C# WinForms`, and I can't figure out how I could make a custom menu strip that appears on click, like the one below

[image: this one].

Comment: Have you tried the (.NET)given menu strip and failed? -> https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s4p1.html. You can change color and background color -> to match your printscreen

Comment: When I add a menu strip, it gets on the top of everything, and I can't change that https://imgur.com/4TMX77R

Comment: So you want it appear above the `MHDesktop`? Your latest comment is very different than your question.

Comment: I would like the menu to display when you click on Help, which is a button

Comment: Why not use the menu strip?

Comment: Because it gets above everything

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look. Also this is getting `a lot off topic` from your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the background color `myMenuStrip.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;`.
To change the foreground color `myMenuStrip.ForeColor = Color.White;`

Also you can move it inside your winforms -> Check this question -> [Tool, menu strip - how do I change their locations in c# winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081621/tool-menu-strip-how-do-i-change-their-locations-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: But my control isn't a menuStrip, it's a button on a panel

Comment: As i mentioned in the comments, if your only issue with the menu strip is placement. You can change that. I am not familiar with a custom solution. With panels and buttons.

Comment: mmm so now I have my menuStrip, how can I change the color on hover, because it's blue now https://imgur.com/1HiL07N, and also the colors of the menu when it's opened https://imgur.com/xTwXowD ?

Comment: Try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777688/c-sharp-how-to-change-menustrip-hover-color. There is a lot of material out there.

Comment: It works fine, but there is only one thing left : the white around the buttons https://imgur.com/o04a8Kr

Comment: Try this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528697/windows-forms-menustrip-border-color.